# Setting gravity inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment with an ScrollView and inside two LinearLayouts. I want to be able to put the first LinearLayout on the top (gravity top) and the second one on the bottom. Here is my code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:context=".activities.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/darkblue"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_drawler_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_drawler_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_drawler_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_drawler_time_avariable"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/txt_drawler_time_avariable"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_drawler_time_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/empty"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/id_drawable_scrollView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="top">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_home"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/btn_drawler_home"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_select"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/btn_drawler_class_select"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_toc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/btn_drawler_toc"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_faq"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/btn_drawler_faq"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_contact"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/btn_drawler_contact"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_drawler_logout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/btn_drawler_logout"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Seems that the child of the ScrollView can't fill_parent or match_parent. Is this possible?

What I want to achieve

[image]

Thank you

**Update 1**

I am not sure why is not working with this structure, in this last case scroll is not working.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayoyt>
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayoyt>
        </LinearLayoyt>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayoyt>
</RelativeLayout>
```

By the way, I find a setup that works for me (With different xml layouts), but I am not sure why that doesn't work and maybe someone can help me to understand.

Comment: put image, i didn't understand what you want and what is the current condition

Comment: This question makes no sense. A `ScrollView` potentially has an infinite height depending on the number of views it contains (and their combined heights). The concept of "top" or "bottom" of a `ScrollView` effectively only exists after it has been created and populated with the various views. Putting something at the "top" of a `ScrollView` and something else at the "bottom" (presumably with some sort of gap in the middle) isn't how a `ScrollView` is meant to work.

Comment: Thank you @Squonk. You helped me to understand what was happening better, but my problem is if the elements inside the ScrollView are smaller than "the height I have" the ScrollView is filled with a white background at the bottom, and I prefer that filler in the middle, in between the two LinearLayouts that are child of a LinearLayout that is the child of the ScrollView.

Comment: You want the elements inside the scrollview to fit the scroll view if they are less in numbers. Is this your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `LinearLayout`, just use `RelativeLayout` (as a wrapper in `ScrollView`). And then instead of gravity top and bottom, use:

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in the top `LinearLayout`
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the bottom `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thank you, I am almost there, with your answer I was able to set the display that I want. I used two RelativeLayouts one for the whole view and another RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView to set the bottom LinearLayout. The problem is that if that two elements are overlapping ScrollView doesn't work and I cant drag the screen.

Comment: thank you, is not the solution, but the best answer. Finally I ended up using this answer and defining layouts for different screens. That's why I will mark this answer as the correct.

Comment: @agusgambina Thanks, but in order to fully help you I would need to know what is your layout goal.

Comment: Thank you @IvanSkoric I will update a little bit the question, but is fine for me now the solution I got.

Answer (score 0):

the linear layout that you want to be in the bottom of the view is under another linear layout who has "center|top" gravity so the second linear layout will be in the bottom of the parent layout
try to make the second layout as a parent not as a child of another layout